# Rules of Inference argument has multiple steps?

Tags: logic

I need to write the rules of inference and explain which rules of inference are used for each step. This looks like it's just Modus Ponens from what I wrote the equations as, am I missing some steps or is this really that simple?

> “There is someone in this class who has been to France. Everyone who goes to France visits the Louvre. Therefore, someone in this class has visited the Louvre.”
>
> C(x) “x is in this class”, F(x) “x has been to France”, L(x) “x visited the Louvre”
> ∃x(C(x) ∧ F(x))
> ∀x(F(x)→L(x))
> ∃x(C(x) ∧ L(x))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out and I think this is 100% correct for the answer. My logic could be incorrect thought since I'm still learning this stuff.

> C(x) “x is in this class”, F(x) “x has been to France”, L(x) “x visited the Louvre”
>   1. ∃x(C(x) ∧ F(x))
>   2. C(x) ∧ F(x) existential instantiation
>   3. F(x) simplification from 2
>   4. ∀x(F(x)→L(x))
>   5. F(x)→L(x) universal instantiation
>   6. L(x) modus ponens from 3 and 5
>   7. C(x) simplification from 2
>   8. C(x) ∧ L(x) conjunction from 6 and 7
>   9. ∃x(C(x) ∧ L(x)) existential generalization

Comment: That looks pretty good.  If I were you I would distinguish between the bound variable $x$ in steps 1, 4, and 9, and the $x$ in steps 2, 4, 5–8 that represents a particular individual for whom $C(x)\land F(x)$ happens to be true. Perhaps use $k$ for this individual, rather than $x$.

Answer (score 2):

Your rendering into QL, I am afraid, is hopelessly wrong! It is not even well-formed (count brackets!), and anyway you need to represent two premisses and a conclusion, so three separate QL wffs. It should be

$\exists x(Sx \land Fx)$,
$\forall x(Fx \to Lx)$,
so $\exists x(Sx \land Lx)$

For particularly good books on translating into QL, Paul Teller's *Modern Logic Primer* is freely available at http://tellerprimer.ucdavis.edu/  Or there's my *Introduction to Formal Logic*!

Comment: Yeah I realized that as I looked back through the book. I was typing up the answer (from what I understand) hopefully it helps others.